# What does the "golden collar" refers to in this text?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

There is a phrase in F. Scott Fitzgerald's short story "The Offshore Pirate" that is quite confusing to me: **the golden collar**. 
 Is it some kind of a landform? Is it simply a way to describe an island, whose shape at first seems to be thin and collar-like? But then how would it become wider later (see quote below)? I guess it could not happen because they moved closer to it, as the yacht is not moving (it is "riding at anchor").

> About half-way between the Florida shore and the golden collar a white steam-yacht, very young and graceful, was riding at anchor and under a blue-and-white awning aft a yellow-haired girl reclined in a wicker settee reading The Revolt of the Angels, by Anatole France. ... The second half-lemon was well-nigh pulpless and the golden collar had grown astonishing in width, when suddenly the drowsy silence which enveloped the yacht was broken by the sound of heavy foot
> steps ... Five o clock rolled down from the sun and plumped soundlessly into the sea. The golden collar widened into a glittering island; and a faint breeze that had been playing with the edges of the awning and swaying one of the dangling blue slippers became suddenly freighted with song.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full context is this:

> The Offshore Pirate I This unlikely story begins on a sea that was a
> blue dream, as colorful as blue-silk stockings, and beneath a sky as
> blue as the irises of children's eyes. From the western half of the
> sky **the sun was shying [throwing out] little golden disks** at the
> sea—if you gazed intently enough you could see *them* [the disks] skip
> from wave tip to wave tip *until they joined a broad collar of golden
> coin that was collecting [coming together] half a mile out and would eventually be a
> dazzling sunset*. About half-way between the Florida shore and the
> golden collar a white steam-yacht, very young and graceful, was riding
> at anchor and under a blue-and-white awning aft a yellow-haired girl
> reclined in a wicker settee reading The Revolt of the Angels, by
> Anatole France.

Ok, so **these disks** [round reflections from the sun] looked as if they we hitting the tops of the waves. [skipping over them, moving across them]. They moved all the way to a "broad collar of golden coin": this is another sun reflection that looks *like* a broad collar [a collar, as found on shirts or dresses or other clothes'] made of golden coin. So this mirage collar looked like it was made of a gold coin. This mirage over the water is what would become the sunset.

The whole thing is about the mirage the narrator/viewer describes of **sun hitting the water and then becoming a sunset**. Before it becomes a sunset, this second reflection looks like a golden collar that is reflected back from the sea to the viewer/narrator.

The golden collar is a reflection mirage. The golden collar is made up of those disks. Like a necklace. And eventually one can see that **it is, in fact, an island**. The girl was on the yacht which was riding at anchor off the Florida coast and this island.

[Gutenberg text of the story](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/4368/4368-h/4368-h.htm)